Azure React deployment not loading
I'm trying to deploy a react application on azure web services. I followed all the steps on this article which got me to a status where the deployment is marked successful but the application is not accessible on the azure site.
Added a screenshot for reference below

I logged into the service through a cli session and checked if the data is available in the wwwroot folder which did have the build files in it.

Would be really thankful if any one of you can assist me to get this deployed
--- UPDATE ----
app log stream is showing the following

Connecting to log stream...
2024-09-02T10:58:05  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----
/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/container.log
2024-08-30T17:55:04.0960916Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage , HttpCompletionOption , CancellationTokenSource , Boolean , CancellationTokenSource , CancellationToken )
2024-08-30T17:55:04.0960941Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy.ProxyMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-08-30T17:55:04.0960967Z    at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 107
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1259705Z [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware1
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261136Z       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261175Z       System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261328Z          at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage , Boolean , CancellationToken )
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261374Z          at Kudu.Services.Web.Tracing.TraceMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /tmp/KuduLite/Kudu.Services.Web/Tracing/TraceMiddleware.cs:line 107
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261430Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
2024-08-30T17:55:04.1261456Z          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---


What does your azure app service log stream show ?

@Ip_nave : Could you share the full app service log stream? Looks like its failing at startup.

@rohit i have updated the logs

@Ip_nave : I am a bit confused. You said you are hosting a react app on azure app service but the logs have Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware. Are you sure you have shared the logs from correct app service?

What do you mean by "the application is not accessible on the azure site" ? Are you receiving 400, 404, 500, 502, blank page? Inspect the browser and share us the details

@Ip_nave are you using Linux or Windows Azure web app?

I believe that you haven't correctly configured your Azure App Service to host static web apps.
First of all, an Azure App Service isn't really ideal for static web apps (which your compiled React app essentially is). You should really be looking into use Azure Static Web Apps. These are meant to host frontends developed using React, for example.
You could also consider, if price is a factor, to host the site on an Azure Storage Account using the Static Web option. You could then simply use Azure CDN on top to handle HTTPS certificates, Default Pages (index), Custom Domains, Caching, etc.
If you decide to stick with Azure App Service, you should be able to get your React app to work by changing your App Service's runtime environment to Node.
You can do this by heading to your Azure Portal, then over to your App Service. Once inside, you'll want to head to Settings --> Configuration in the right-hand side panel. Once there, select Node as the stack.

This worked,, I had to shift to azure static web app
